# Volume of a solid with substitution and without

Tags: integration, volume

I am trying to find the volume of a solid **located in the first octant** and bounded by surfaces $z=x+y$, $xy=1$, $xy=2$, $y=x$, $y=2x$, $z=0$.

I set up the following integral:

$V = \int_{1/\sqrt 2}^1 \int_{1/x}^{2x} (x+y)dydx + \int_1^\sqrt 2 \int_x^{2/x} (x+y)dydx$.

I integrated it, checked it with Wolfram and it equals $\frac{4-\sqrt2}{3}$.

This is not the answer that I have in the textbook, but I believe the integration was correct as Wolfram gives the same result. So, I think either I set it up wrong or the answer in the textbook is wrong.

I also tried doing this integral using substitution. Setting $u=xy$, $v=y/x$, I got

$V=\int_1^2 \int_1^2 (\sqrt{u/v}+\sqrt{uv})|I| dvdu$, where

$I= v/2$.

This is the result of integration:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_1%5E2+int_1%5E2+(sqrt(x%2Fy)%2Bsqrt(x*y))*y%2F2+dydx

Again, when I integrate it, the result is the same as what I get with Wolfram. But it is not the same as using the first method or what is in the textbook. I am totally confused.

Comment: You should not have a $v$ in your final answer because it is a dummy variable. The result should be a pure number.  Without seeing your work we can't find the problem.

Comment: I don't have $v$ in my final answer. I wrote that it's a Jacobian. As I wrote, Wolfram gives the same answers as mine, so I am concerned not with the answers, but with the set up. Are my integrals correct for the given region?

Comment: your integral is correct and it's answer is $\dfrac{4-\sqrt{2}}{3}$. Integrate directly.

Comment: The Jacobian is $\dfrac{1}{2v}$.

Comment: Finally https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_1%5E2+int_1%5E2+(sqrt(u%2Fv)%2Bsqrt(uv))(1%2F(2v))du+dv

Comment: @MyGlasses, thank you so much! So, my answer was actually correct without substitution. And yes, I made a mistake with the Jacobian.